# R MICE imputation failing

Tags: r, statistics, r-mice

I am really baffled about why my imputation is failing in R's `mice` package. I am attempting a very simple operation with the following data frame:

```r
dfn <- read.table(text =
"a b c  d
 0 1 0  1
 1 0 0  0
 0 0 0  0
NA 0 0  0
 0 0 0 NA", header = TRUE)
```

I then use mice in the following way to perform a simple mean imputation:

```r
imp <- mice(dfn, method = "mean", m = 1, maxit =1)
filled <- complete(imp)
```

However, my completed data looks like this:

```r
filled
#     a b c  d
#1 0.00 1 0  1
#2 1.00 0 0  0
#3 0.00 0 0  0
#4 0.25 0 0  0
#5 0.00 0 0 NA
```

Why am I still getting this trailing `NA`? This is the simplest failing example I could construct, but my real data set is much larger and I am just trying to get a sense of where things are going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Okay, so it seems that the issue is being caused by one column being a perfect linear combination of some of the others. Any idea about how to handle this in real data?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has been cross-posted on stats.stackexchange.com: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/127104/11849

Comment: @Roland Yes, I posted it there as well and a user gave the reason for the issue in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how accurate this is, but here is an attempt. Even though `method="mean"` is supposed to impute the *unconditional* mean, it appears from the documentation that the `prdictorMatrix` is not being changed accordingly.

Normally, leftover `NA` occur because the predictors suffer from multicollinearity or because there are too few cases per variable (such that the imputation model cannot be estimated).
However, `method="mean"` shouldn't behave that way.

Here is what I did:

```
dfn <- read.table(text="a b c  d
 0 1 0  1
 1 0 0  0
 0 0 0  0
NA 0 0  0
 0 0 0 NA", header=TRUE)

imp <- mice( dfn, method="mean", predictorMatrix=diag(ncol(dfn)) )
complete(imp)

# 1 0.00 1 0 1.00
# 2 1.00 0 0 0.00
# 3 0.00 0 0 0.00
# 4 0.25 0 0 0.00
# 5 0.00 0 0 0.25
```

You can try this using your actual data set, but you should check the results carefully. For example, do:

```
sapply(dfn, function(x) mean(x,na.rm=TRUE))
```

The means for each variable should be identical to those that have been imputed.
Please let me know if this solves your problem.