# Imputing values in all columns of data.frame with mice

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I am trying to impute values using a linear model using mice. My understanding of mice is that it iterates over the rows. For a column with NAs it is using all other columns as predictors, fits the model, and then samples from this model to fill up the NAs.
Here is an example where I generate some data, and than introduce missing data using ampute.

```
    n <- 100
    xx<-data.frame(x = 1:n + rnorm(n,0,0.1), y =(1:n)*2 + rnorm(n,0,1))
    head(xx)
    res <- (ampute(xx))
    head(res$amp)
```

The missing data looks like:

```
            x         y
   1       NA  3.887147
   2 2.157168        NA
   3 2.965164  6.639856
   4 3.848165  8.720441
   5       NA 11.167439
   6       NA 12.835415
```

Then I am trying to impute the missing data:

```
   mic <- mice(res$amp,diagnostics = FALSE )
```

And I would expect that then there is non, but there are NA always in one of the columns.

```
 colSums(is.na(complete(mic,1)))
```

And in which of the two it is rather random.

By running the code above I am getting:

```
 > colSums(is.na(complete(mic,1)))
  x  y 
  0 30
```

but also :

```
 > colSums(is.na(complete(mic,1)))
  x  y 
 33  0
```

Comment: I am unsure what is exactly your question. What would you like to do?

Comment: impute missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to run your code and end up with the same type of problem:

```
library(mice)
n <- 100
xx<-data.frame(x = 1:n + rnorm(n,0,0.1), y =(1:n)*2 + rnorm(n,0,1))
head(xx)
res <- (ampute(xx))
head(res$amp)
```

if you look at the `summary` from the `mice` call then you get an indication that something is wrong. My data gives

```
tempData <- mice(res$amp,m=5,maxit=50,seed=500)
summary(tempData)
Multiply imputed data set
Call:
mice(data = res$amp, m = 5, maxit = 50, seed = 500)
Number of multiple imputations:  5
Missing cells per column:
 x  y 
21 23 
Imputation methods:
    x     y 
"pmm" "pmm" 
VisitSequence:
x 
1 
PredictorMatrix:
   x  y
x  0  0
y  0  0
Random generator seed value:  500
```

There are two indicators here. One is `VisitSequence` which shows that only the first column is visited, `x`, and not column `y`. Also, the `PreditorMatrix` only contains zeros in the off-diagonal so none of the predictors use information from any of the other predictors.

The problem is in your simulated data because the two columns are too colinear, and a similar solution is given in [this detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330570/mice-does-not-impute-certain-columns-but-also-does-not-give-an-error). Because the `y` column is essentially twice the value of the `x` column it is silently discarded from the analysis.

Try to simulate data that are not almost perfectly linear and it will work. For example a quadratic relationship

```
n <- 100
xx<-data.frame(x = 1:n + rnorm(n,0,0.1), y =(1:n)**2 + rnorm(n,0,1))
head(xx)
res <- (ampute(xx))
head(res$amp)
```